# Converting RDD with 1500 columns to Dataset using createDataFrame() throw exception GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection" grows beyond 64 KB

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am using the Spark 2.1.0 release

I am trying to load BigTable CSV file with more than 1500 columns into our system.

**Our flow:**

- First, read the data as an RDD
- generate continuing record id using the zipWithIndex()
     (this operation exist only in RDD API, 
      in the Dataset there is similar option which is monotonically_increasing_id() 
      but this method work in partitioning and create id which is not sequentially – and it is not what we need ☹)
- converting the RDD to Dataset using the createDataFrame() of sparkSession
- this last operation generate code that exceeded the JVM object size limitation of 64KB

I search the web for some solution or even similar Use Case, 
found few issues that talked about the 64KB error but all of the cases was dealing with 100 column and solved in Spark 2.1.0 version by shrinking the generated code, 
but none of them reach the JVM limitation

**Any Idea from this forum of expert will be very appreciated**

there could be 2 type of solution we are looking for:

1. How should I overcome the size of the code generation

### OR

2. How can I generate sequential ID directly on the Dataset

**Our Temporal Solution:**

- reading the DS as RDD
- generate sequential id
- write the new data as text file
- reading the data as Dataset
  this solution cause us 30% of performance degradation :(

**Code That reproduced the issue**

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import poc.commons.SparkSessionInitializer;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class RDDConverter {
    private static final int FIELD_COUNT = 1900;

    private Dataset<Row> createBigSchema(SparkSession sparkSession , int startColName, int fieldNumber) {
        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());
        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());

        String[] row = IntStream.range(startColName, fieldNumber).mapToObj(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);
        List<String[]> data = Collections.singletonList(row);
        JavaRDD<Row> rdd = jsc.parallelize(data).map(RowFactory::create);

        StructField[] structFields = IntStream.range(startColName, fieldNumber)
                .mapToObj(i -> new StructField(String.valueOf(i), DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()))
                .toArray(StructField[]::new);
        StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(structFields);

        Dataset<Row> dataSet = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema);
        dataSet.show();
        return dataSet;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSessionInitializer sparkSessionInitializer = new SparkSessionInitializer();
        SparkSession sparkSession = sparkSessionInitializer.init();

        RDDConverter rddConverter = new RDDConverter();
        rddConverter.createBigSchema(sparkSession, 0, FIELD_COUNT);
    }
}
```

**The Exception we are getting :**

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$codegen$CodeGenerator$$doCompile(CodeGenerator.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:950)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:947)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.codehaus.janino.JaninoRuntimeException: Code of method "(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V" of class "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection" grows beyond 64 KB
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.makeSpace(CodeContext.java:941)
```